# Hibernate restore soft-deleted entity

Tags: java, hibernate, soft-delete

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Usermaster]")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE Usermaster SET isDeleted = 1")
@Where(clause = "isDeleted = 0")
public class User {
//...
}
```

Now when I delete some Entity it actually will set deleteFlag = 1
How can I restore the entity?

thanks

Comment: Probably update the flag to 0 using sql/hql?

Comment: but how can I find User when every time when I run query, I can get only non-deleted users?

Comment: If you use a session.get() this where condition will be applied, but, if you use a hql asking for both isdeleted =0 | 1 it will bring what you asked for.

Comment: I'm using CRUD repositories to get entities. Here my select query:
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u where u.userEmail = :email AND u.isDeleted = 1")
 User getDeletedUser(@Param("email") String userEmail);

it still doesn't work since is_delete = 0 is appended

Comment: @EvgenyMakarov did you solve this issue?

Comment: @jax I didnt use these annotations in the end

Comment: @EvgenyMakarov did you find another neat solution?  Are you able to share it?  I am having the same issue - I need to be able to disable filtering in certain circumstances.

Comment: @jax not anything special. Just making query to mark entity as deleted and filtering out (using @ Query annotation) deleted entities when retrieving data from repo