# Hibernate how to ignore @Where annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Usermaster]")
@Where(clause = "isDeleted = 0")
public class User {
//...
}
```

in some flow I need to ignore @Where annotation and get user even if isDeleted is not 0. How can I make it? (I use CRUD repositories to query)

Comment: I was trying to do the same approach. What was your solution?

Comment: I've decided not to use Where nor Filter. Just made regular queries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656518/hibernate-restore-soft-deleted-entity appending here to link questions

Answer (score 7):

There is a dynamic version of the `@Where` setting, it is the `@Filter`. See:

- [19.1. Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

> Hibernate has the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach those filters at both a class level and a collection level. A filter criteria allows you to **define a restriction clause similar to the existing `"where"` attribute** available on the class and various collection elements.

Management of @Filter is a bit more complex, in a nutshell:

- `<filter-def>` / `@FilterDef` is needed to define filter
- `<filter>` / `@Filter` must be assigned to class or a set
- filter must be enabled on a session level, e.g.: `session.enableFilter("myFilter").setParameter("myFilterParam", "some-value");`

So, this, while being a bit more complex, provides exactly what we need: dynamic *`@Where`* to be turned on/off in run-time

Comment: @Filter is turned off by default so in order to apply it allover the system I'll need to add code in many places. I'm looking for transparent solution so I'll be able to add new code only for a few cases when I don't need the filter

Comment: Yes, `@Filter` management is a bit more challenging. On the other hand this is the way - the only way - how to evaluate `@Where` dynamcially. I.e. `@where` is a fixed mapping. No way how to turn it off. I know that it is not as nice answer as you wanted... but on the other hand, **my experinece with filter like this, is really good**. With some **AOP** in place, it is **enabled automatically** for us... let's say 99% cases. If needed, we can turn it off..and that works ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I've tried to find a way to find the code where new session is created by spring-data in order to figure out how I can override it and put my code that enables the @Filter, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but the answer might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962006/1917300):

> simple solution is to use native SQL:

```
lst = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
createSQLQuery("select {entb.*}  from EntityB entb where  is_deleted=1")                            
       .addEntity("entb", EntityB.class)
       .list();
```

Comment: Do you know, if it happens of the same way when using @Query with JPQL?

Comment: it should work with JPQL, best guess is just to try it.

Comment: thanks for sharing, this opens a lot of refactoring points for my native query implementations